# Expected value of quotient of identically distributed random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expectation

What is example of two identically distributed random variables so $$\\ 
E\left(\frac XY\right) \neq E\left(\frac YX\right) 
$$
I know they have to be dependent, but I still don't have any idea.

Answer (score 3):

How about $(X,Y)=(1,2)$ or $(2,3)$ or $(3,1)$ each with probability $\frac13$?